# Is $\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, means

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ is a sample drawn from some population, if we use $\max(X_1, X_2,X_3)$ as an estimator of the population's mean, then can we say that its unbiased:

My approach was to let $X_{ i}$ be the max, $i=1,2,3$ and then deduce that $E(X_{ i})=\mu $, so did I miss anything?

Edit:

It appears due to the comments that $\max(X_1, X_2,X_3)$ follows a different distribution, given that the population is exponential how should I go around this sort of problem.

Thank you.

Comment: $\max\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ does not follow the same distribution as the $X_i$s.

Comment: If $X_i \sim {\rm Unif}$ then $E[\max\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}] = 3/4$. These are [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: Well, it follows the exponential distribution.

Comment: For the exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ the expectation of the maximum is $11/(6\lambda)$. Again this is called the *largest order statistic* of a sample of length 3.

Comment: Any hints on how can one derive this? I would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> given that the population is exponential

just a detail...

As known, the distribution of the max is the product of the single CDF's, thus in your case, setting

$$Z=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$$

you get

$$F_Z(z)=\left(1-e^{-\theta z}\right)^3$$

derivating you get the density

$$f_Z(z)=3\theta e^{-\theta z}\left(1-e^{-\theta z}\right)^2$$

with expectation

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\int_0^{+\infty}3z\theta e^{-\theta z}\left(1-e^{-\theta z}\right)^2dz=\frac{11}{6\theta}$$

Concluding: the estimator is biased for the mean of the population, $\mu=\frac{1}{\theta}$, but with a correctable bias

Comment: Alright, thank you. We should be integrating and multiplying by z in the last step, right?

Comment: @Malzahar you're welcome. In order to simplify the calculations of the expectation note also that $E(Z)=\int_0^{\infty}[1-F_Z(z)]dz$

Comment: @Malzahar: I mixed x and z...any variable is z in the integral....amended the obvious typo